# Linq-to-SQL Executing NonQuery

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to use Linq-to-Sql to execute a stored procedure that does not return an output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Server Explorer window, browse and find your sproc. Drag it over to the Methods area in the Linq-to-Sql designer.

This stored procedure is now available as a method in your DataContext object.

e.g.

Your sproc name is `IncrementCustomerVisit` and it takes one parameter of type `int`.

In your app code:

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
   db.IncrementCustomerVisit(someCustomerID);                 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`DataContext.ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.ExecuteCommand("exec myStoredProcedureName");
```